# Keyboard blinks when AutoCompleteTextView dropdown is shown

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview, dialogfragment

I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView` inside `DialogFragment`. When it shows a dropdown list, keyboard hides and shows again very fast, it looks like a blink.

As possible solution, I found that it happens because of

```
AutoCompleteTextView {

    showDropDown(){
       mPopup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
    }
}
```

So overriding showDropDown() in this way removes blink

```
showDropDown(){
    super.showDropDown()
    mPopup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE)
    mPopup.show()
}
```

But it shows dropdown above keyboard and blocks user input. Maybe someone knows better solution?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Seems to be new to android Q. I'll keep looking, but I got about as far as you did (at which point I came across your question).

Comment: @etrado I have not found any solution. So I replaced `AutoCompleteTextView` with `TextInputEditText` and a `ListView` (with filterable `ArrayAdapter`) inside `ConstraintLayout` looks ok. But you need to handle `ListView` visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to believe this, but I am pretty sure the December 5 patch to android Q fixed this problem. I got the update this morning, and I was hoping since it was a relatively new issue that they might have addressed it. Turns out they did! I get no more flashing keyboard when using the AutocompleteTextView.